# Adding NPM and Bower to a Dockerize LAMP environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

While I am still reading and learning about Docker more and more doubts comes out. If I am not wrong the idea behind Docker is to have a dedicated service per container (micro-services). So if we want a LAMP environment a good choice would be 3 or 4 different containers handling PHP, Apache|Nginx, MySQL and maybe a fourth one with code.

Now I am going beyond my knowledge limits and I want to add support for tools such as NPM and Bower for work with AngularJS basically and others libraries but I don't have a clue in how this should be added.

So:

- It's fine to add NPM as part of the packages installed on each container as mention before? Let's said add into the sources container?
- Where would you add it?
- How would you handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done easy using docker-compose: https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/

You can entirely separate bower, npm or just use one container called `app` for example.

- The first choice consider using image based on node, so you can
  install grunt or bower using npm install inside each container. After
  every installation  docker will commit a new "slice" to container.
- The second one consider you to pull just all-in-one image
  `nodejs-bower-grunt` for example that already has all stuff out of
  box.

I suggest you to read these two articles to get clear how it's done:

[Prepare provisioning with Docker](https://medium.com/@tomsowerby/proper-provisioning-with-docker-c412211b97bb#.u07bapcxd)

[How to use docker for local web development](http://tech.osteel.me/posts/2015/12/18/from-vagrant-to-docker-how-to-use-docker-for-local-web-development.html)

Comment: The first article says: *- .:/data => mounts your empty folder into the /data directory on the container* I am confused about it, can you try to illuminate me? What that does exactly? What the author mean with `empty folder`?

Comment: Sorry for late, it means that you mount your current directory (where docker-compose.yml is created) to the data folder in container. You can simply mount another directory `~/PhpstormProjects/Project1:/var/www/data`.